# realurl prevar language and get parameter

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have a strange problem:
TYPO3 7.6 with realul 2.2.1

I got a page with a form. One field of the form gets prefilled via get-parameter (sysid=xxxxx).

The site is multilanguage: german->0, english->1, mapped via prevars '' and en.

When I call the page via www.domain.tld/form-page/?sysid=xxxxx I can fetch the get parameter and fill the field.

When I call the page via www.domain.tld/en/form-page/?sysid=xxxxx I get a 404. That's weired because www.domain.tld/en/form-page/ works without any problems.

I tried several settings (e.g. exclude sysid from chash generation) but nothing worked.

Any hints what I could do?

One additional note: the getvar links are not generated in TYPO3, the are called via barcodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Error occured because I didn't adjust the realurl-setting for the domain after moving to live. Therefore automatic configuration took place and that didn't work. With manual conf it works.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem on the same versions of T3 and realurl.
And I guess (wild guess), it is not a realurl problem, but a TYPO3-core problem.
Could you try calling the page via:
www.domain.tld/index.php?id=XX&L=1&sysid=xxxxx

Furthermore investigate and tell us your settings of
[FE][pageNotFound_handling] and according (installtool/LocalConfiguration).

Comment: ```'FE' => [
        'additionalAbsRefPrefixDirectories' => 'uploads/',
        'cHashExcludedParameters' => 'L, pk_campaign, pk_kwd, g, m, sysid',
        'cHashIncludePageId' => true,
        'debug' => false,
        'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa',
        'pageNotFoundOnCHashError' => '0',
        'pageNotFound_handling' => '404/',
        'pageUnavailable_handling' => '404/',
    ],```

Comment: Calls via `www.domain.tld/index.php?id=XX&L=1&sysid=xxxxx` or `www.domain.tld/form-page/?sysid=xxxxx&L=1` do work